# Publishing WCF applications

Tags: windows, wcf, publish

I'm a little new to WCF. I've created a WCF service on my local machine, it's published to the inetpub directory on my C:\ drive.

I'm supposed to have it running on another machine for Q/A. It's running Win Server 2003, but I don't see an inetpub directory. Can I publish my WCF to this machine, or do I need to install some sort of web services?

There is a 'wmpub' directory, should I just publish my WCF there?

Thanks for any/all help!

-Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your windows seems to be missing **IIS**.

Have a look [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998483%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can choose where you put it, it's a matter of configuration.

Your best bet would be to package the WCF service with WebDeploy, then run that package on the target server.

It's very easy and you can build your deployment package straight from within Visual Studio 2010. Check out http://www.iis.net/download/WebDeploy for more.

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a [self hosted service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx) or [host it in IIS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amitlale/archive/2007/05/21/hosting-wcf-service-in-iis.aspx)